# save is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to insert a 'caso' in my db but I get an error saying that `caso.save is not a function`. I already tried a thousands of different ways to insert and none worked. Am I doing something wrong?

PS: My `caso.find(...)` is working fine!

The server side code:

```
app.post('/api/casos', function (req, res) {
        var caso = new Caso();
        caso = req.body;

        caso.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json({message: "Caso adicionado com sucesso!"});
            }
        });
    });
```

The controller code:

```
$http.post('/api/casos', $rootScope.caso).success(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
```

My 'caso' model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Caso', {
    caso: Number,
    doenca: String,
    areaDamaged: String,
    cankerLesion: String,
    cropHist: String,
    date: String,
    externalDecay: String,
    fruitSpots: String,
    fruitingBodies: String,
    fruitPods: String,
    germination: String,
    hail: String,
    intDiscolor: String,
    leafMalf: String,
    leafMild: String,
    leafShread: String,
    leafspotsHalo: String,
    leafspotSize: String,
    leafspotsMarg: String,
    leaves: String,
    lodging: String,
    moldGrowth: String,
    mycelium: String,
    plantGrowth: String,
    plantStand: String,
    precip: String,
    roots: String,
    sclerotia: String,
    seed: String,
    seedDiscolor: String,
    seedSize: String,
    seedTmt: String,
    severity: String,
    shriveling: String,
    stem: String,
    stemCankers: String,
    temp: String
}, "casos");
```

The req.body JSON:

```
{ areaDamaged: 'low-areas',
  cankerLesion: 'dk-brown-blk',
  cropHist: 'same-1st-yr',
  date: 'Abril',
  externalDecay: 'Absent',
  fruitSpots: 'dna',
  fruitingBodies: 'Absent',
  fruitPods: 'dna',
  germination: '90-100%',
  hail: 'Yes',
  intDiscolor: 'None',
  leafMalf: 'Absent',
  leafMild: 'Absent',
  leafShread: 'absent',
  leafspotsHalo: 'absent',
  leafspotSize: 'dna',
  leafspotsMarg: 'dna',
  leaves: 'Abnorm',
  lodging: 'Yes',
  moldGrowth: 'Absent',
  mycelium: 'Absent',
  plantGrowth: 'Abnorm',
  plantStand: 'lt-normal',
  precip: 'Normal',
  roots: 'Norm',
  sclerotia: 'Absent',
  seed: 'Norm',
  seedDiscolor: 'Absent',
  seedSize: 'Norm',
  seedTmt: 'none',
  severity: 'pot-severe',
  shriveling: 'Absent',
  stem: 'Abnorm',
  stemCankers: 'below-soil',
  temp: 'norm',
  caso: 1,
  doenca: 'phytophthora-rot' }
```

Comment: Would you add your post body JSON?

Comment: I suppose your `req.body` has a `save` method, if not, you're overriding your caso object by doing `caso = req.body;`

Comment: @BasimHennawi sure, just a moment.

Comment: @NickRameau I don't think so, take a look in the req.body

Comment: `var caso = new Caso();caso = req.body;` what... what are you doing... that can't possibly be intended.

Comment: @KevinB Exactly what I said earlier

Comment: @KevinB calm down, I just started with MEAN stack, I am learning man.. Never did this before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `save` method you're trying to use is part of the Model, not your `req.body`. So you have to get rid of that line:

```
caso = req.body;
```

Because it's overriding that line:

```
var caso = new Caso();
```

Comment: Now I got it. So, I will have to set each value to my new caso. Like, caso.doenca = req.body.doenca... Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Accept the answer if it helped please. @GustavoMendonça

Comment: @GustavoMendonça or `var caso = new Caso(req.body)`